# ArangoDB Traversal with conditions on vertice's neighbours

Tags: arangodb, aql

I have the following graph:
[image]

I'd like to write a AQL query that returns paths, starting from the node `Q1`, in which the second node in the path has the neighbour `P6` (neighbours of the start node `Q1` always have a P-node (`P6`, `P4`, ..) in its neighbourhood).

For example, the good paths are : `Q1->Q1-P6-3->STRING-2`, `Q1->Q1-P6-3->Q1-P6-3-QUAL-P2-2->QUANT-2`, etc.
What is the best way to check the condition? For now, I've added to nodes such as `Q1-P6-3` an attribute `property` with the key of P-node from its neighbourhood and just filter paths:

```
FILTER p.vertices[1].property == 'P6'
```

But I believe there is a smarter way to do that. 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AQL first gets the list of all nodes that have P6 as a direct neighbor and then uses that to filter the paths in the traversal query. This way you do not need to keep track of the property in the vertices:

```
LET p6Neighbors = (FOR t IN testEdge
                    FILTER t._to == 'test2/P6'
                    RETURN t._from)
for v,e,p in 1..5 ANY 'test2/Q1' testEdge
FILTER p.vertices[1]._id in p6Neighbors
return p
```